# Python, возврат (return) из функции

Tags: python

Есть такой код, который принимает список с нулями, а на выходе должен выдать список с именами из другого списка (насколько хватит имен):

```
days = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
lessons_time = ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Коля', 'Саша', 'Игорь', 'Славик']


def get_fill_slots(i, lst, all_days):
    lessons_times = lst
    if len(lessons_times) == 0:
        return all_days
    else:
        all_days[i] = lessons_times[0]
        lessons_times.pop(0)
        print(len(lessons_time), all_days)
        i += 1
        get_fill_slots(i, lessons_times, all_days)

a = get_fill_slots(0, lessons_time, days)
print(f'A: {a}')
```

Для наглядности я добавил принт на каждой итерации, который показывает, что объект **all_days** все время работы функции является списком, и что условие возврата функции выполняется, вот только возвращается мне не список, а **None**.

```
5 ['Вася', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4 ['Вася', 'Петя', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3 ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Коля', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2 ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Коля', 'Саша', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1 ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Коля', 'Саша', 'Игорь', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
0 ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Коля', 'Саша', 'Игорь', 'Славик', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
A: None
```

Кто может подсказать, почему так происходит?

Comment: забыли сделать return в последней строке `return get_fill_slots(i, lessons_times, all_days)`. А вообще то, это проще можно `a = lessons_time + days[len(lessons_time):]`

Comment: Спасибо!!
А что это за конструкция? Как она работает, в двух словах?
a = lessons_time + days[len(lessons_time):]

Просто сложение списков?
Мне там еще условия добавлять нужно будет, поэтому оставлю свою рек-функцию, но все равно интересно.